# findOneAndUpdate the latest document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

This is my schema

```
 var BudgetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user_email: { type: String, required: true },
  user_budget: { type: Number, required: true },
  platforms_budget: {
    type: [{
      platform_id: { type: String, required: true },
      platform_name: { type: String, required: true },
      platform_budget_percent: { type: Number, required: true },
      platform_budget: { type: Number, required: true },
    }]
  },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});

var BudgetSchemaExport = module.exports = mongoose.model('Budget', BudgetSchema);
```

And this is the function:

```
module.exports.updateBudgetPercent = async function (user_email, platform_name, p_budget) {
  var query = {
    "user_email": user_email,
    "platforms_budget": {
      $elemMatch: { "platform_name": platform_name }
    }
  };
  //the location that need to be updated
  var update = { "$set": { "platforms_budget.$[outer].platform_budget_percent": p_budget }  };
  //array's index
  var options = { arrayFilters: [{ "outer.platform_name": platform_name }] };
  var updated = await this.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).sort({ created: -1 })
  if (updated) { //if the data was updated
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The purpose of the function is to update a budget for specific user.
I want to update the latest document, but it updates the earliest/first one.

I tried this option: `var updated = await this.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, {sort:{ "created": -1 }})`, but I got an error:

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: callback.apply is not a function
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: So you have more than one documents for the same `user_email` and you want to update the latest document.
Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 7):

Use `upsert: true` with `sort: { created: -1 }`. Here is the query:

```
var updated = await this.findOneAndUpdate(
  query,
  update,
  {
    upsert: true,
    sort: { created: -1 },
  }
);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, but I still have a callback error. I need to pass options as well and according to this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate if I pass 4 arguments, the 4's argument is a callback.

Comment: Also, I tried this, but it doesn't change anything.  var update = { "$set": { "platforms_budget.$[outer].platform_budget_percent": p_budget },upsert: true,
  sort: { created: -1 } };

Comment: Ok, here I can see that your `update` variable is a single object that has 3 fields. One is `$set` operator, second `upsert` and third `sort`.

But actually in the `findOneAndUpdate` method there are 3 different parameters. Do not use `upsert` and `sort` at the update stage.

I gave you the query that has 3 parameters  `query`, `update` and third is an object that has two fields `upsert` and `sort`. You are clubbing both of them with update may be that is the reason they are not working.